# What is the significance of PAsha and Ankusha?

Tags: devi, weapon, symbolism, parvati

What is the importance PAsha and Ankusha in Devi's hands?
I didn't see these in Sri Parvathi's hands, as Sri Parvathi either holding Kumara in one hand and Lotus in another hand, when along with Mahadeva 
OR
 in the SwayavaraParvathi sankalpa (only holding Maala in front of Mahadeva).

I saw in Srividya krama, Goddess with Pasha, Ankusha.

Why Sri Parvathi is not having Pasha and Ankusha?

if I meditate Devi with Pasha and Ankusha, whats the benefit am going to get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasons why the Goddess holds Pasha (noose) and Ankusha (goad) in her hands are mentioned in [Lalita Sahasranama of the Brahmanda Purana](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/brahmandapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=31).

The Ankusha indicates that she is controlling the devotees from going astray and the Pasha indicates that she corrects them from time to time.

> Om Aim Hreem Shreem Shri Matrey Namah/
>
> Shri Maataa Shri Mahaaraahni Shrimat Sihaasaneshwari,
>
> Chidagni Kunda sambhhutaa Deva Kaarya Samudyataa/
>
> Udyadbhaanu Sahasraabhaa Chaturbaahu Samanvitaa,
>
> Raaga Swarupa pashaadhyaa Krodha Kaaraankushojjwalaa/
>
> Manorupekshu Kodanda Pancha Tanmatra Saayakaa,
>
> Nijaaruna Prabhaapura majjadbrahmaanda mandalaa/
>
> Champakaashoka sougandhika lasatkacha,
>
> Kuruvindamanishreni Kanatkotira mandita/
>
> Sacred Mother!You are the Extraordinary Queen seated on the Throne
>   mounted by lions; You are generated from the fire-pit of
>   self-realisation; You sparkle with the lustre of thousand Suryas with
>   four arms **with a goad in the right hand as though you spur your
>   devotees to follow the right path and at the same time displaying your
>   displeasure with a noose up your upper left hand to correct them
>   where-ever necessary;** Devi! You carry a sugar-cane bow with the
>   determination of materialising the Universe with your left lower hand,
>   while actually taking up the deed of Creation with the aid of Five
>   Tanmatras or Elements by another hand of yourself. Indeed the
>   magnificence of your creation is spread all over as Omnipresent. Your
>   Hairdo is endowed with the natural perfume of Champaka-Ashoka-Punnaaga
>   flowers; You are embellished with a Crown bejewelled with special
>   precious stones of Kurukulla as though they signify various emotions
>   and feelings.

As you can see the verses mention Ankusha to be of Krodha swarupa. So, it is the fear of this anger of Devi that keeps devotees from going astray. And, Pasha is mentioned as Raga swarupa. It is this passion (or compassion) due to which Devi corrects devotees whenever necessary.

Regarding your other question about Goddess Parvati - I don't think its possible to answer why a certain deity is not carrying some object. Instead we can answer why it is carrying some particular object like I have done above.

Answer (score 3):

The different forms of the deities have been revealed to the rishis who have composed the dhyana-mantras.As Swami Nigamananda writes

> The formless brahman assumes form to shower grace on the devotee (Tantrik-Guru,Sarasvata Math, page 56).

Its also said :'Sadhakaanaam hitaarthaya brahmano rupakalpana' : For the benefit of the aspirants, Brahman assumes forms.

So why One holds it and other does not ---this question has no answer in the scriptures. Some prefer to explain these symbolically, but thats upto them.

The same about the benefit.The dhyana is a part of puja.(Reference: Sastramulak Bharatiya Saktisadhana,Upendrakumar Das,RMIC, Vol 1, page 923).Any puja can be sakama, that is for gaining sme material thing or for attaining one of the eight siddhis (Ashta-Siddhi) or five types of Mukti(Panchavidha Mukti)or Moksha(Merging with Brahman). Worship can also be out of pure devotion or a way of getting pure devotion.That has to be mentioned while uttering the sankalpa-mantra as per the puja-vidhi. Devi is 'Chaturvarga-falapradaa' meaning She can bestow Dharma, Artha, Kaama and Moksha (Upendrakumar, page 335). A dhyana-Mantra of Bhavani reads

> arunaam karunaataramgitaakshim dhrita-paasha-ankusha-mukhyachaapa-hastam/Animaadibhir aavritam mayukhair ahamiti eve vibhavaye Bhavanim//

meaning:  I mediate on Mother Bhavani, who is red-coloured, eyes full of grace, holding paasa and ankusha, dhanur and vaana in four hands and is sorrounded by eight siddhis like Anima etc.

According to Tantra, Paasa are of eight types that binds a jiva and so Devi by Her grace can remove these paasha.According to the Kularnava-Tantra (13/30-31), the eight 'paasa' are

> Ghrina,Lajjaa,Bhaya, Shanka, Jugupsa,Kula, Shila and Jaati.

Also,

> ghrina shanka bhayam lajja jugupsa cheti panchami/ kulam silam cha maanam cha astau pashah prakirtitah//
>   iti ashtapaashah kevalam vandhanarupa rajjavah/
>   etair vaddhah pashuh prokto mukta etaih sadashivah// (Vairava-yamala)

Paasa also is used to mean Moha-paasha(bondage of Attachment) or Maya-pasha(bondage of worldliness).Devi is known as Mahamaya Who binds the jeevas by Her noose. And being pleased by worship, grants boon and frees from Her noose (Reference: Sri Sri Chandi, chapter 1, mantras 53-56).

Ankusha is the instrument to control an elephant. In our scriptures, mind is compared to a mad-elephent (matta kari) as Sri Ramakrishna refers to in His Kathamrita(Udbodhan, page 246,22 July 1883), which can be controlled by Devi with Her Ankusha.

But I repeat, Devi appears physically to the saints and so She has form, as mentioned in Kenopanishad (Uma Haimavati).